# How to recreate a TextField widget with my own behavior?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I would like to create a test application with PyGTK.

My goal is to create a textfield widget 100% customized. Indeed, I would like to fully change the default behavior of a textfield widget.

Is it possible to fully change the behavior of a textfield (like shortcuts/keymaps, scroll behavior, etc.) ?

Is it possible to recreate the widget from scratch ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to a gtk.Entry or a gtk.TextView?

In any case, you are going to want to subclass the widget you want to customize and override any methods that you need to change. If you can read C code, that would be helpful as you can look over the widget source code. If you've never written your own widgets, you might want to start with a tutorial like http://www.learningpython.com/2006/07/25/writing-a-custom-widget-using-pygtk/

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate it from scratch. Derive from it instead and overload what you intend to change.